# Google map with URL Scheme?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am trying to get direction using google map.
I am following this link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme?hl=en

**and code:**

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
        NSString *temp=@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=Google+Inc,+8th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY&daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&directionsmode=transit";

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
    }
```

the map is not opened,i am getting:

> Installation[2918:1295695] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "comgooglemaps://" - error: "(null)"

what was the problem? did i miss anything?

I want to show google map from my application.

Answer (score 1):

> In iOS 9 you must whitelist any URL schemes your App wants to query in
>   Info.plist under the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key (an array of
>   strings):

[image]

Quote taken from here http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html

Comment: i did this already as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Google Maps app is installed in your device before making the function call or else the canOpenURL: function will return null.